# Creating Rest url with comma separated and multiple parameters

Tags: java, rest, http, okhttp

i would like to create rest url for get request like

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?parameters=value1,value2|value3,value4 & key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I am using okhttp client to create it, but am confused how do i create value1,value2|value3,value4.

I am unable to find any option which adds multiple values for same query parameter.
Is there any option that can be used or should i do it manually with loop?? 
Also since , and | are special characters should i use encoded values ? for ex: %2c for , when creating manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something like below.

```
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads").newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("parameters", "value1,value2|value3,value4");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("key", "YOUR_API_KEY");
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
```

Whether you should be doing loop or something else for `value1,value2` etc, depends on, how you are fetching this values in your application, since question is less clear on that, its hard to answer that part. Regarding | to %2c, I think you should be doing it.

Comment: thx for the reply... yes my doubt was if there was any inbuilt method to use, but i guess from your answer i understand that should do manually

Comment: Good to know. Please accept as correct answer if serve your purpose.